# Construction of $\mathcal O(-1) \oplus \mathcal O(-1)$ over $CP^1$

Tags: gauge-theory, supersymmetry

First, Consider a $\phi$ as a coordinates on a copy of $Z= C^N$

Then, I know 
\begin{align}
|\phi_1|^2 + |\phi_2|^2 + \cdots |\phi_N|^2 = r
\end{align}
which describe $S^{2N-1}$.

Implementing $U(1)$ condition the space of solution is described by

\begin{align}
CP^N = S^{2N+1}/U(1)
\end{align}
Now consider slightly different case 
\begin{align}
|\phi_1|^2 + |\phi_2|^2 - |\phi_3|^2 - |\phi_4|^2 =r
\end{align}
this gives **$\mathcal O(-1) \oplus \mathcal O(-1)$ over $CP^1$. 
I want to know what this means and how to obtain.**

Many references related to Mirror symmetry, cover this for granted. I want to understand the meaning precisely.

cf) relevant question already asked by me [[Moduli space for $CP^N$ and $T^{*} CP^N$ in $\mathcal{N}=2$ SUSY](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/154495/moduli-space-for-cpn-and-t-cpn-in-mathcaln-2-susy) ] , and  [
[meaning of $\mathcal O(-1)$ in algebraic-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1501182/meaning-of-mathcal-o-1-in-algebraic-geometry)]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a crosspost of [the math.SE post linked in the question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1501182/143136).